# How to programmatically (via AppsScript) open a specific Sheet in a Google Spreadsheet via URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a source Sheet with URLs in.  Those URLs point to specific target Sheets (tabs) in other Spreadsheets.  (If I click the links manually they open to the correct Tab/Sheet.)

The URLs look like this:
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<spreadsheetID>/edit?resourcekey=<ignored>#gid=<sheetid>`.  (The "gid=NNN" part identifies the Sheet (tab) in the Spreadsheet to make active.)

I can use `const sprd = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)` to open the target Spreadsheet programmatically.  But to get a specific Sheet (tab), the only useful API I can find is `getActiveSheet()` but that is documented as returning the Sheet "shown in the UI".  But this Spreadsheet isn't show in the UI.  And AFAICT, for programmatic access, the "active" sheet is always just the first sheet in the Spreadsheet, independent of what "gid" was in the URL passed to openByUrl().

As a work-around I can parse the "#gid=NNNN" out of the URL.  And then openByUrl() the Spreadsheet, invoke `getSheets()` and compare the gid pulled out of the URL against the `.getSheetId()` of each sheet until it is found.  AFAICT, there is nothing like an `getSheetByID()` API on the Spreadsheet.

Is there some other approach that I'm missing?

Comment: Why not `getSheetByName()`?

Comment: I haven't any Sheet names, as far as I know.  The URLs are copied out of the browser when visiting a tab, so they're in the Sheets-defined format.  I don't have control over what goes in the URL.  (Unless the GID is also a "name", that might simplify the work-around.)

Comment: If you don't have the sheet name, then, as you've said, loop through and get the ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function requires you to paste the url into a prompt.  It will open up the spreadsheet by url and get all the data on the current sheet and display it in a dialog and at the end it will display the name of the sheet.

```
function getData() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const r = ui.prompt('Url Dialog', 'Enter Url', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (r.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    const url = r.getResponseText()
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    let id = url.slice(url.indexOf("=") + 1);
    let sh = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => sh.getSheetId() == id)[0];
    let vs = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    let s = '<textarea cols="50" rows="12"> ';
    vs.forEach((r, i) => {
      if (i > 0) {
        s += ['\n'];
      }
      s += r.join(',');
    })
    s += `\nSheet Name: ${sh.getName()}</textarea>`
    ui.showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(800), 'Title');
  }
}
```

Url Dialog:

[image]

Data Dialog:

[image]

Scroll down to the bottom to see the sheet name.

Comment: This would work if i had more control over the format of the URLs I'm using.  But we're just copying those URLs out of the browser when visiting a Sheet, so as far as I know, there is no "name" available to use.

Comment: Thanks for building a working example!  Nicely done.  Would love to see a real API for this, but at least its possible to roll our own.  The gid extraction from the URL might be more robust if you use something like `url.match(/gid=([0-9]+)/)[1]`

Comment: I think the = sign is a pretty good delimiter

Answer (score 1):

Posting this for documentation purposes.

As others said, loop through the sheets to find the sheet with the correct `id`.

The most appropriate way would be to use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
const sheetId = url.match(/gid=([0-9]+)/)[1];
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
const sheet = ss.getSheets().find(sheet => sheet.getSheetId() == sheetId);
```